# Filtering the item in dataframe which does not appear in other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frame `d1` and `d2`. Both of them has a column called `value`.

I want to separate d2 to two data frame: d3 and d4. d3 should contains the rows with `value` does not appear in `d1`, and `d4` contains the rows from `d2` with `value` appear in `d1`.

I tried:

`d3 = d2[!is.element(d2$value, d1$value),]`

But it seems not correct: the items of `d3` is not as expected.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Update**:

It seems that `anti_join` is not the solution

The sample data:

```
d1 = as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
colnames(d1) = "value"

d2 = as.data.frame(c(7,8,9,10,11,12))
colnames(d1) = "value"
```

So, `d3` should contain `9,10,11,12` (because 9,10,11,12 do not appear in d1) and `d4` should contain `7,8` (because 7,8 appear in d1)

Comment: Hello, I think my question is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data can be expressed this way:

```
d1 <- data.frame("value"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
d2 <- data.frame("value"=c(7,8,9,10,11,12))
```

But really those don't need to be data.frames, they are just vectors.

```
d3 <- d2[! d2$value %in% d1$value,]
d4 <- d2[d2$value %in% d1$value,]
```

This results in d3 and d4 being vectors since that is basically what the input was anyway. If the data.frames had more than 1 column then you would get data.frames as the result object.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `anti_join` to get the elements in one dataset that are not in the other

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(d2, d1, by = 'value') %>%
                           arrange(value)
#    value
#1     9
#2    10
#3    11
#4    12
```

For getting the common elements, either `merge` or `inner_join` from `dplyr` can be used.

```
inner_join(d1, d2, by ='value')
#   value
#1      7
#2      8
```

---

Another approach is `setdiff`, and `intersect` from `dplyr`

```
 setdiff(d2, d1)
 intersect(d1, d2)
```

NOTE: Assuming that there is only a single column.

Comment: At least make them provide sample data and an expected output!

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen  Thanks for the comment.  I thought it was straightforward from the description.

Comment: Hello @akrun, I want to join by rows, not by columns, but anw thank you very much for your answer and sorry for my question if it is not clear

Comment: @mamatv Please check the answer.  It is the same as your expected.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen  The OP had updated with a sample and expected output